# How to create an ansible-vault file from a task

Tags: ansible

I need to create an ansible-vault file to store credentials in a task in a playbook. This file would be used by another playbook. Is there an internal ansible method/module to accomplish this? I would prefer not to do it invoking shell/command. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no ansible-vault module, ansible-vault is a command line program.

Generic command, script, or shell tasks could work, if a specialized module is not available.  `ansible-vault encrypt` in this case.